# Concat array in TypeScript and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: arrays, typescript, visual-studio-2015, concatenation

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 when I try to apply the `concat`method to a numeric array:

`supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. Candidates are:
(...items: undefined[][]) => undefined[]
(...items: undefined[][]) => undefined[]`

The error appears exactly at `[].concat(data)`

```js
function foo(a: number, b: number): number {
  // some code
}

export function bar(data: number[], param2: number, param3 = false): number {
 if (!param3) {
  data = [].concat(data).sort(foo);
 }
 // Some more code
}
```

The error disappears if I change the type of the parameter data to `data: any[]`but I don't want to do that, I want `data`to be a numeric array. I'm not getting this error In Webstorm nor VS Code, so it has to be something related with Visual Studio. I uninstalled old versions of TypeScript just in case, and only installed the last one (2.0.3). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by overwriting/concating the input `data`. Do you want to have a new array object?

Comment: Could also be an issue with Sudio2015 since no other editor shows the error. From a syntax standpoint this looks fine, too.

Comment: I'm sure it's Visual Studio, even in the typescript playground the code works as expected, hope next update will solve the issues. I'll be working on VS Code or Webstorm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while this wasn't an issue in WebStorm and VS Code, in Visual Studio it was necessary to cast the array: `<Type>[]` or `([] as Type)`, in my case I had to cast it to 

`any`: `<any>[].concat` or `([] as any).concat`